# Decomposing a sequence with countable number of accumulation points into convergent sub-sequences in metric space

Tags: general-topology

> Let $S$ be any metric space and the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has an infinite but countable number of accumulation points $y_1,y_2,...$ Prove that it is possible to split the index set $\mathbb N$ into a disjoint union of sets $S_j, j=1,2,...$ such that each sub-sequence $\{x_n\colon n\in S_j\}$ converges to $y_j$.

---

My attempt:

I am able to deal with the situation when $\{y_n\}$ has no limit point. Since we can decompose $S$ as a union of compact subspaces(not necessarily disjoint), whilst we can choose a uniform radius $\epsilon$ for each accumulation points, such that there is no other limit point within the $\epsilon$-ball for each $y_i$, then we conclude that there are only finite points not lying in the union of $\epsilon$-balls in each compact subspaces. Therefore it is possible to split the index set $\mathbb N$ into a disjoint union of sets $S_j$ such that each sub-sequence $\{x_n\colon n\in S_j
\}$ converges to $y_j$.

However, I am stuck in the case when $\{y_j\}$ does have at least one accumulation point. Can someone give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: Choose one point that is close to $y_1$.  Then choose two points that are close to $y_1, y_2$ respectively.  Then choose three points...

Comment: @NateEldredge But how can we be sure that they are all $\{x_n\}$ without missing a point?

Comment: If you find there were some points that you didn't use, just dump one of them into each of the $S_i$.  This won't affect their limit points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First choose subsets $N_1, N_2, N_3, \ldots$ of $\Bbb N$ such that $(x_n)_{n \in N_i} \to y_i$ for each $i$. This can be done by standard facts.

Set $N_0 = \Bbb N \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty N_i$, the unused indices.

Now note that for $ i\neq j $ we have $|N_i \cap N_j|$ is finite (or we'd have a common subsequence with two distinct limits, which cannot happen).

Now just redistribute the finite intersections and $N_0$ over the other $N_i$ to make it into a partition. It's just a set theory fact on almost disjoint subsets of $\Bbb N$. Adding or subtracting finitely many terms from a convergent sequence has no effect on its convergence or limit, so you have room to play with.

Comment: The spirit is so much like Hilbert's Hotel. I think this is the right way to deal with the countable infinity. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you explain more on how the redistribution of $N_{0}$ and the intersections $N_{i} \cap N_{j}$ results in only adding finitely many terms to the $N_{1}, N_{2}, N_{3}, \dots $?

Comment: To add to user100101212's question, I'm a little confused as to why $N_0$ can be assumed to be finite. For instance, suppose $S$ is the set of real numbers and we have a sequence $\{T_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ of real sequences $\{x_{m,j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ each converging to zero but with increasingly slower rates: more precisely for some $\epsilon>0$, the sequence $\{M_{m ,\epsilon}\}_{m=1}^\infty$, -  where for each $m \in \mathbb N$, $M_{m, \epsilon}$ is the least natural number $n$ such that $|x_{m,n}|<\epsilon$ for all $n>M_\epsilon$, - is unbounded (or in other words, ....

Comment: .... $\sup_{m \rightarrow \infty} M_{m, \epsilon } = +\infty$). "Patch" the sequences $\{T_m\}$ together into a single sequence $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ (for example, as $x_{1,1}, x_{1,2}, x_{2,1}, x_{3,1}, x_{2,2}, x_{1,3}, x_{1,4}, \cdots $, one of the ways of establishing the countability of the set of rationals). Suppose  $\{x_n\}$ contains $\{y_n\}$ as a subsequence, so that zero is one of the (countable-infinitely many) limit points of $\{x_n\}$. Then $N_1$ may just be the sequence $\{x_{1,j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ whereas $\mathbb N \setminus N_1$ is infinite ...

Comment: ...and it could happen that $N_2, N_3, \cdots $ are disjoint from $\mathbb N \setminus N_1$ (by "patching in" other countably many sequences with different limit points in the construction of $\{x_n\}$) , so that $N_0 := \mathbb N \setminus \bigcup_{j \geq 1} N_j$ is infinite. How is it possible to do an inductive redistribution to get disjoint convergent sequences partitioning $\{x_n\}$?